# Cannot add derby nature to project

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, derby

I am having trouble adding (and removing) derby nature to my projects. I did manage to add and run derby in one of my projects but now I can't add it to any new ones (dynamic web project or java).

I am getting this error:

> Error adding Derby jars to the project 'web222' :
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow
>   cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow"

I am using `Eclipse Juno EE`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400225/where-did-the-apache-derby-eclipse-plug-in-go?rq=1