# Apache Derby nature cannot be added

Tags: derby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did the Apache Derby Eclipse plug-in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400225/where-did-the-apache-derby-eclipse-plug-in-go)

I installed several Derby plugins for Eclipse in the Eclipse plugins folder e.g. `org.apache.derby.core_10.2.2`, `org.apache.derby.plugin.doc_1.1.0` and `org.apache.derby.ui_1.1.0`

I am doing this for a Java EE project. When I try to add the Apache Derby nature to this type of project, it gives the following error:

> error adding derby jars to project
>   :org.eclipse.ui.internal.workbenchwindow cannot be cast to 
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow

I'm using Eclipse Juno.

Comment: Try this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400225/where-did-the-apache-derby-eclipse-plug-in-go?rq=1

Comment: facing the same issue :(

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645223/is-it-possible-to-use-derby-from-apache-in-eclipse-now-that-they-stopped-develop?rq=1