# Apache derby plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

After installing the [JavaDB plugin](http://archive.apache.org/dist/db/derby/db-derby-10.3.1.4/) for eclipse version 4.3.2, I unzipped the core and ui folders and put their contents under eclipse/plugin directroy.

unfortunately, clicking on a project, and adding apache derby nature lead for nothing!
No packages is added to the project, and no control panel is available for the apache derby!
I can repeat the process 10s times and nothing happened.

I'm new with the environment, help me out!

Ps; you should be able to see packages added to eclipse java ee kepler.

[image]

Comment: Your link is to a very old version of Derby. 10.10 is current. Support for the Eclipse plugins were dropped some time ago.

Comment: I didn't find a plugin for eclipse basied in derby 10.10.1.
Any suggestion? @greg-449

Comment: There are no longer any plugins. You just use the Derby jars like any other external jar.

Comment: Try this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400225/where-did-the-apache-derby-eclipse-plug-in-go?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @BryanPendleton. it was really useful, and a bit complicated!
May I ask if it's possible to install apache derby on ubuntu 14.04 and work on it with the eclipse without adding any plugin?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Certainly, Derby by itself works fine on Ubuntu 14.04.