# Apache Derby Plugin Errors

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

Using

```
jdk1.6.0

Eclipse IDE (Win32) version kepler

derby_ui_plugin_1.1.0  and

derby_core_plugin_10.1.1
```

Problem

When trying to add a new derby nature (right-click on the java project -> "Apache Derby" -> "Add Apache Derby nature")

I only get the following message:

Apache Derby Ui Plug-in
Error adding Derby jars to the project:
org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow cannot be cast to
org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow

Any ideas?

Comment: The derby UI plugin is very old and does not work with Eclipse 4.x, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11400225/2670892