# Why eclipse doesn't see derby plug-ins?

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

I'm knew to eclipse and as expected I have a problem.

Problem with installing

- derby_core_plugin_10.8.2.zip
- derby_ui_doc_plugin_1.1.3.zip

from http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.8.2.2.html

I've read manual that says "download zips, extract them to `ECLIPSE_HOME`, they should be in `/plugins` directory and then restart eclipse", but that doesn't work.

Also I tried to restart eclipse with `-clean` option, again no result.

The magic "Apache Derby" option in project context menu doesn't appear.

I'm working with the latest release of eclipse luna and old eclipse workspace (mean that workspace stayed from previous release). At the moment I'm guessing that cause is .metadata folder, is it ?

Comment: Probably this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400225/where-did-the-apache-derby-eclipse-plug-in-go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that plugins in zips `derby_core_plugin_10.8.2` and `derby_ui_doc_plugin_1.1.3` are no longer supported not just by Apache Derby project, but also in Eclipse IDE. As I know this plugins work well in Eclipse versions `3.X.X`, but for now the latest available eclipse realease have varsion `4.X.X` and there is no option to have them in this version.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-EclipseDbWebapps/index.html