# Where from can I get derby core plugin for eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

Good day!

Where from can I get a new derby core plugin for eclipse?

I found the link

> http://archive.apache.org/dist/db/derby/db-derby-10.3.1.4/?C=M;O=A

but there are releases are dated by 2007 year.

Maybe there are another ways(tools) to work with derby db from eclipse?

Comment: The plugin is no longer maintained. Just use the derby jar file.

Comment: Can you tell me a little bit more, please? Here "http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_howto.html" I could read about plug-ins. Where can I read about the modern tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find current downloads for Apache Derby Database [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html). Version 10.11.1.1 is from August 26, 2014. So i assume it is maintained here.
There is also documentation ('*modern tools*') contained in the download. I use it without any plug-in for some IDE.
Just a few first steps (windows batch):

create database (all in the same line):

> set jvm=*path_to_java.exe*
>   "%jvm%" -jar "%~dp0db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin\lib\derbyrun.jar" ij "%~dp01_db_create.sql">"log.txt"

1_db_create.sql:

> CONNECT 'jdbc:derby:database;create=true';
>   CREATE TABLE MYTABLE 
>   (
>    ARTIKEL_NR varchar(35) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL 
>   , SPRACHE varchar(3) DEFAULT ' ' NOT NULL 
>   , PRIMARY KEY 
>    (
>      ARTIKEL_NR 
>    , SPRACHE 
>    ));

start server that listens to port 1527 (all in the same line):

> set port=1527
>   set jvm=*path_to_java.exe*
>   set cp=*path_to_db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin\lib**
>   "%jvm%" -cp "%cp%" org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl start -p %port%

connect server to fire sql commands:

> set dbname=database
>   set port=1527
>   set user=app
>   set pass=app
>   set jvm=*path_to_java.exe*
>   set cp=*path_to_db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin\lib**
>   set options=-Dij.connection.data=jdbc:derby://localhost:%port%/%dbname%
>   "%jvm%" -cp "%cp%" %options% org.apache.derby.tools.ij

This connects to the db and you can fire some sql's like `select * from mytable`

Comment: See also this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400225/where-did-the-apache-derby-eclipse-plug-in-go